# Grafana/Loki: Log lines get highlighted with the search i used in the log panel in grafana from the use of my log select

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

The lines are getting hightlighted with the search I used and doesn't seem to be a way to disable it. For example.

I used the following query and got

```
{host="server-01",job="systemd-journal",systemd_unit="appmx.service"} |~ `INFO:DB:flushed`
```

[image]

Notice how that part is highlighted in orange, i wasn't able to remove it.

I did a workaround but not sure its good for performance, i added the following to the end of the query

```
 | regexp `(?P<message>.*)` | line_format "{{.message}}"
```

This does fix it but seems I might be doing it wrong.

Anyone have any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a  `| decolorize` that is normally just for stripping ANSI color sequences, but maybe could work for you as well.

i.e.

```
{job="example"} | decolorize
```

See: https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#removing-color-codes